# Struggling to communicate with the utorrent web API

Tags: javascript, php, utorrent

I am trying to access utorrents web api, it uses a token authentication system which is detailed [here](https://github.com/bittorrent/webui/wiki/TokenSystem)

the JavaScript on my page is

```
        <script>
            $.getJSON("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/lib/token.php", function(response) {
                var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                //script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                //    if (this.readyState == 'complete') utorrent();
                //}
                //script.onload = utorrent();
                script.src = 'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/gui/?list=1&token=' + response.token;
                head.appendChild(script);
            });
        </script>
```

simply retrieving the token from a php file and passing it along the chain, i have confirmed that the token is being passed and is not being poisonned, my PHP document is below

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/json');
$token = file_get_contents('http://[username]:[password]@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/gui/token.html');
$token = str_replace("<html><div id='token' style='display:none;'>", "", $token);
$token = str_replace("</div></html>", "", $token);
$response = array('token' => $token);
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

this gives me a confirmation of the token
Object {token: "GMt3ryaJE64YpXGN75-RhSJg-4gOW8n8XfTGYk_ajpjNLNLisR3NSc8tn1EAAAAA"}

but then i receive a 400 error code when retrieving the list
GET http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/gui/?list=1&token=GMt3ryaJE64YpXGN75-RhSJg-4gOW8n8XfTGYk_ajpjNLNLisR3NSc8tn1EAAAAA 400 (ERROR)

Any help/thoughts/idea's would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

just adding my 2 cents.

I've been doing a similar implementation in .NET MVC - I was able to get the token as you did, but the list=1 feature didn't work for me either, getting the 400 bad request code (as you have found).

The solution for me:
In the token.html response, there is a token in the div **and also a GUID** in the header.

To break it down:

1. Call token.html with uTorrent credentials
2. In the response content, parse the html to get the token
3. in the response header, there is a value with key `Set-Cookie`, which looks like

   `Set-Cookie: GUID=<guid value>`
4. I needed to use this value (`GUID=<guid value>`) in all requests being sent back, as well as the token and it worked!

I'm not sure what the implementation is in PHP to do this however :)

Also quick note, I've been trying to get values through jQuery's `$.getJSON` and `$.Ajax` method without any success, because the browser (chrome) I'm using has strict guidelines on cross domain requests, and it doesn't look like uTorrent is implementing `JSONP`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

use `text/plain` or `application/json`, not `text/json`.

`application/json` sometimes causes issues on Chrome, so you might want to stick with `text/plain` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The 400 Error message means you are communicating with a bad request. 
The MIME media type for JSON text is application/json .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the order of the query parameters?

eg: `http://localhost:8080/gui/?token=<token_uuid>&list=1`

Reference: https://github.com/bittorrent/webui/wiki/TokenSystem#examples

---

**UPDATE**
I ran into a similar problem trying to create and XMPPBot for utorrent client in python.

@m.t.bennett was correct. You need to save the session information as well.

When you receive the response from *token.html*, capture the cookie information as well.
Usually there are 2 params: *GUID* and *sessions*. You need to put them in the header for all your subsequent requests -- List API, Getfiles API, etc.

This should fix your problem!